# Why does the height of my Constraintlayout increase when I place it in a Scrollview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-editor

I have a ConstraintLayout which shows all items on my smartphone without the need to scroll. Nevertheless I want to surround the ConstraintLayout with a ScrollView that a user with smaller phones can scroll.

When adding the ScrollView, even on my smartphone I need to scroll to reach the last to buttons. The height of the ConstraintLayout increases and the two buttons with id="@+id/button3" and id="@+id/button4" appear after a big empty area.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_black_24dp"
    android:onClick="zurueckZuMainActivity"
    android:text="Zurück"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
    android:onClick="weiter"
    android:text="Weiter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Bestellformular"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Schritt 1/4: Lieferadresse"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.523"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"


    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/vorname_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Vorname"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"


        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_nachname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Nachname"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:id="@+id/nachname_edit"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.587"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_nachname">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Telefonnummer"
        android:id="@+id/telefonnummer_edit"
        android:inputType="number"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="E-Mail-Adresse"
        android:id="@+id/email_edit"

        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="248dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.361"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp" />


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_stadt"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_nummer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Straße"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"

        android:id="@+id/strasse_edit"

        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_nummer"
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/nummer_edit"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Nummer"


        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_plz"
    android:layout_width="108dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_stadt"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:hint="PLZ"
        android:id="@+id/plz_edit"
        android:inputType="number"

        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_stadt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayout_plz"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_nummer"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Stadt"
        android:id="@+id/stadt_edit"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"


        />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:text="Füllen Sie bitte alle nachfolgenden Felder aus! "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your `Buttons` in their own `ConstraintLayout`, inside `linearLayout3`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="weiter"
        android:text="Weiter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="zurueckZuMainActivity"
        android:text="Zurück"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

yu have used fillviewport="true" which basically increases the height of your scroll view to use remaining space if there is extra space available in viewport. If you will make it false, the height of the viewport will be as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Bestellformular"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Schritt 1/4: Lieferadresse"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.523"
            />


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"


            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/vorname_edit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Vorname"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"


                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_nachname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Nachname"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:id="@+id/nachname_edit"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.587"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_nachname">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Telefonnummer"
                android:id="@+id/telefonnummer_edit"
                android:inputType="number"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_telefonnummer">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="E-Mail-Adresse"
                android:id="@+id/email_edit"

                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="248dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.361"
            />


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_stadt"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_nummer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Straße"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"

                android:id="@+id/strasse_edit"

                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_nummer"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/nummer_edit"
                android:layout_width="163dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Nummer"


                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_plz"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_stadt"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_strasse">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="106dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:hint="PLZ"
                android:id="@+id/plz_edit"
                android:inputType="number"

                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_stadt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayout_plz"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_nummer"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Stadt"
                android:id="@+id/stadt_edit"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"


                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:text="Füllen Sie bitte alle nachfolgenden Felder aus! "
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_vorname"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="zurueckZuMainActivity"
        android:text="Zurück"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="weiter"
        android:text="Weiter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `fillviewport="true"` which basically increases the height of your scroll view to use remaining space if there is extra space available in viewport. If you will make it `false`, or just remove that attribute, the height of the constraint layout will be as you expected. By default, the value of `fillviewport` is false.